# Opening a certain Activity depending on which Radio Button is selected?

Tags: android, android-intent, radio-button, radio-group

I've got a RadioGroup with two buttons in it.

I have a "Create" button that when pressed, starts *one of two activities*. If the first RadioButton, **search**, is checked when the "Create" Button is pressed,  it should open the "ProductSearch" activity.

If the second RadioButton, **type**, is checked when the "Create" Button is pressed,  it should open the "TypeEntries" activity. For now, though, it opens "ProductSearch" no matter which RadioButton is pressed.

So it works for **search** but not **type**.

```
  RadioButton search = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
  RadioButton type = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);

  Button create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create);
  if(search.isChecked()){
      create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent createIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProductSearch.class); // <----- START "SEARCH" ACTIVITY
            startActivityForResult(createIntent, 0);
        }
    });
  }else if(type.isChecked()){
      create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent typeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TypeEntries.class); // <----- START "TYPE ENTRIES OUT" ACTIVITY
            startActivityForResult(typeIntent, 0);

        }
      });
    }    
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
RadioButton search = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
  RadioButton type = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);

  Button create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create);
  create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if(search.isChecked()){
            Intent createIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProductSearch.class); // <----- START "SEARCH" ACTIVITY
            startActivityForResult(createIntent, 0);
            }
            else
            {
              if(type.isChecked())
              {
              Intent typeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TypeEntries.class); // <----- START "TYPE ENTRIES OUT" ACTIVITY
              startActivityForResult(typeIntent, 0);
              }
            }
        }
    });
```